# Disable automatic locale detection in next-intl on first visit

Tags: next.js, next-intl

I'm using next-intl with nextjs app directory as shown in their docs https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#disable-automatic-locale-detection

```
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
 
export default createMiddleware({
  // ... other config
 
  localeDetection: false
});
```

it disables locale detection from both `accept-language` header and cookies. What I want is to disable locale detection only from `accept-language` header but use cookie values if present.